# Irreducibility at compositions of polynomial expressions in general?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, irreducible-polynomials, elementary-functions

Let $P(X),Q(X),p(X)\in\overline{\mathbb{Q}}[X]$ (or $\mathbb{Q}[X]$) and let $P(X),Q(X),p(X)$ be not constant.
Let $P(p(x))=Q(x)$.

Let's consider irreducibility over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ (or $\mathbb{Q}$).

1. In which cases can the irreducibility of $Q(x)$ be concluded from the irreducibility of $P(x)$?
2. In which cases can the irreducibility of $P(x)$ be concluded from the irreducibility of $Q(x)$?

I don't know how I could start to derive an answer.

I need the answer because I want to try to prove some of the conjectures in [Closed-form solvability of elementary transcendental equations?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3411598/closed-form-solubility-of-elementary-transcendental-equations/3411601#3411601).

Comment: Your questions do not make a lot of sense, since $P(p(x))=Q(x)$, then irreducibility on one side is equivalent to irreducibility on the other one. So answer to your questions 1 and 2, as you stated them, should be "always".

Comment: @Ferra Thanks. Now I corrected my question accordingly.

Comment: Why do you need the algebraic numbers $\overline{\Bbb Q}$ for this question? See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3417701/coprimality-at-compositions-of-rational-expressions-in-general).

Comment: @Dietrich Burde In the most general case, I have polynomials over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$. But if the polynomials are over $\mathbb{Q}$, irreducibility over $\mathbb{Q}$ is sufficient. I changed my question accordingly.

Comment: The definition of irreducibility for compositions should also exclude trivial cases like $Q = P \circ I$ where $I$ is the identity polynomial $X$ or things like $X-a$, otherwise all polynomials would be reducible. I guess you want $P$ and $p$ to have degree at least $2$ in order to say that $Q = P \circ p$ is reducible.

Comment: See Schinzel, Polynomials with Special Regard to Reducibility, https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/polynomials-with-special-regard-to-reducibility/FBC37D46462D46A6E121FFC9A09391C5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for question 2, the irreducibility of P(x) follows from the irreducibility of Q(x) as long as p(x) isn’t constant . This can easily be proven by contradiction:
Let p(x) be any non-constant polynomial and suppose P(x) is some reducible polynomial such that Q(x) = P( p(x) ) is irreducible.
Now since P(x) is reducible, it has some factorization into two non-constant polynomials which we will call R(x) and S(x), so P(x)=R(x)•S(x). Substituting this in, we get that Q(x) = P( p(x) ) = R( p(x) )•S( p(x) ). And since p(x), R(x), and S(x) are all non-constant, the compositions R( p(x) ) and S( p(x) ) are both non-constant. This means that the equation              Q(x) = R( p(x) )•S( p(x) )
Is a non-trivial factorization of Q, meaning Q is reducible, contradicting our assumption that it was not. Thus for any p(x), the irreducibility of Q implies the irreducibility of P

If p(x) were constant, Q(x) would also be constant so it would obviously not be irreducible.

The answer to question 1, is that the irreducibility of P implies the irreducibility of Q only when p(x) is linear. With algebraic polynomials it’s easy to see that the only irreducible polynomials are the linear ones since algebraic polynomials always have algebraic zeroes and thus divide the linear polynomials with those zeroes. Returning to the rationals, I can tell you that for any quadratic p(x), there is a linear P(x) which essentially “completes the square” so that Q(x) is a square polynomial (so P is irreducible but Q is reducible).

This can be improved upon because for any polynomial p(x) with degree grater than one, you can let P(x) be the linear function that subtracts the constant term of p(x). As a result, Q(x) will have no constant term, and must divide the polynomial f(x)=x.