# Solution to an equation with logarithms of type $x\log(x) + ax + b = 0$

Tags: logarithms, closed-form, transcendental-equations

I've encountered a transcendental equation with logarithms like $x\log(x) + ax + b = 0$, and I'm wondering if there is a closed-form solution for the equation.

Comment: If you are happy to use the Lambert $W$ function ... then, yes.

Comment: Did you "encounter" the equation in this generic form, or did you have an example with concrete values of $a$ and $b$? (Which values?)

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit I will use the answer of the equation in an optimization, so it's better if I could find the derivative of the answer. I don't know that Lambert W function has a derivative or it should be evaluated numerically.

Comment: @StinkingBishop In my specific problem, $b = -2$, but $a$ can be both positive or negative.

Comment: For a specific value ... use wolfram alpha. If you need to code it up, then you will need to find a library with this function ... or write your own ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect there is no closed form solution.  Transcendental functions such as these usually dont; especially considering the variables $a,b$, there are just too many degrees of freedom and too many unique equations.

Note: I am making the assumption that $\log$ is the natural logarithm.  If this is not so, you can easily modify the math.

We can substitute $x=e^u$ and arrive at the equation $ue^u + ae^u + b=0$.

Rewrite it as $e^u(u+a)=-b$

Multiply by $e^a$ to produce $e^{u+a}(u+a)=-be^a$

Take advantage of the Lambert W function: $u+a= W(-be^a)$

Thus: $$\log(x) = W(-be^a) - a$$

---

In a comment you asked about the Lambert W having a derivative. It does have an implicit derivative:
$$\frac{d W(x)}{dx} = \frac1{x + e^{W(x)}}$$

Comment: I dont see that this is necessary.  All equations without a closed form can be written in a non-elementary closed form if you arbitrarily define a non-elementary function to do the job. Or is that not so?  I think asking if an equation has a closed form sort of implies, at least in spirit, an elementary form.

Comment: You miss my point. Being non-elementary, the Lambert W function is **implicitly** not a closed form solution already.  Had the equation been any different and had its solution taken any other non-closed form, that solution can be made to be closed with the appropriately chosen arbitrarily defined new non-elementary function.  Lambert W was *invented* to turn a non-closed equation into (the appearance of) a closed equation. Unless you can prove this otherwise, I will not be changing my answer.  Im really not sure why youre arguing and trying so hard to discredit a correct answer.

Comment: I understand the imperative to be mathematical. I understand that you *want* to make a distinction between closed forms and elementary solutions.  But if youre going to tell me that expressing answers with Lambert W is both closed and non-elementary then please explain to me why this seemingly arbitrary practice cant be done with **any** expression? Here... lets define $x = C(y)$ to be a closed form expression for the largest root of a quintic polynomial. Arbitrary, but fiat, I know. I shall call it the Cogito C function. Does that satisfy your artificial mathematical needs?

Comment: You want to be mathematical, fine. Be mathematical then. Prove to me that there is a meaningful distinction between closed and elementary.  Prove to me that there arent infinitely many equations that cannot be treated the same way Lambert W treats its solutions.  Prove to me that we cannot on a whim define new and creative non-elementary functions for the sole and deliberate purpose of expressing certain non-closed forms in seemingly closed ways.  Im asking YOU for proof of this claim. Be mathematical now, or please quit arguing the point.

Comment: I dont consider an infinite series to be elementary though.  The infinitude of terms and the potential for conditional convergence sort of disqualify it.  It might contain elementary operations but even the Lambert W function can be expressed as an infinite series of elementary operations, so you have defeated your own argument.

Comment: Also youre using an affirming the consequent fallacy.  I can also assign to your infinite series of non-elementary functions a function name, $H(x)$.  Simply using $H(x)$ on its own, I have made it appear to be closed.  Its arbitrary, man. Its just function naming.  What about this dont you get?  Unless you have something valid to say, Im going to disengage this conversation now. Youre not taking it anywhere productive.

Comment: Then why did you call the Lambert W function closed form?  The definition you are using here contradicts that previous claim.  I didnt make assumptions about what the OP wanted... I just gave an answer. And I told him explicitly it wasnt closed and its obvious by the name that it isnt elementary. What are you arguing for?

Comment: "closed-form expression/solution" are mathematical terms now/today. We should help to use them mathematically.

Comment: You forfeit this discussion by deleting half your conversation with me. Intellectual dishonesty through and through.

Comment: @ CogitoErgoCogitoSum My comment was only an offer/recommendation. Discussing so extensively is not permitted at MathStackExchange here. Therefore you should delete your discussion of my comment here also. If you want to discuss about sense or nonsense of the mathematical terms elementary function/number and/or closed-form function/number, you could ask a new question at MathStackExchange.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of equations cannot be solved by rearranging it by applying a finite number of [elementary functions](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunction.html).

If [Schanuel's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel%27s_conjecture) is true and $a,b\in\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$, the equation doesn't have solutions that are [elementary numbers](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ElementaryNumber.html).

see [Closed-form solvability of elementary transcendental equations?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3411598/closed-form-solvability-of-elementary-transcendental-equations)

As CogitoErgoCogitoSum showed in his answer, the non-elementary solution can be represented as

$$x=e^{W(-b{e^a})-a}=-\frac{b}{W(-be^{a})}.$$
$\ $

---

$$W'(x)=\frac{W(x)}{x+xW(x)}$$