# does the set of number that you can reach by using addition, multiplacation, subtracting, division, and powers on any element on the set, have a name?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I created this new (at least to me) number set, inspired by algebraic numbers, is defined as the set of all numbers that serve as solutions to polynomial equations without  only considering the integers as coefficients and exponents. Each number in this set can be represented as a solution to the general equation $ax^b+cx^d+\ldots+lx^k=0$, where $a, b, c, d, \ldots, l,$ and $k$ are any number found as a root in the set. Notably, numbers such as $\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2}$, and $e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}$ that are not part of the algebraic numbers can be included in this new set. For example, in this expanded framework, $e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}$ satisfies the equation $x^{-i}-i=0$ and $\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2}$ satisfies the equation $x^{\sqrt{2}}-2=0$, making them members of this new set.

Extended set includes the Algebraic numbers, but also contains a lot more numbers. here are my questions.

1. Does this number set already have a name widely used, and if it does, what's the name for it?
2. Are there familiar numbers that don't belong to the algebraic numbers set but are included in this expanded set, like maybe $\pi$ or $e$?
3. Where can I find further resources on this particular topic, especially this way of extending sets, and proving if a number is inside or outside a set?

Comment: Exponentiating a general (say, complex) number by something that's not an integer is not a single-valued function, you have to define branches and avoid ambiguities there.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg you are correct for example $x^i - i = 0$ has infinity many solutions, but even regular integer exponites like 2 can cause multiple possible answers like $x^2 - 2 = 0$ has $\sqrt{2}, -\sqrt{2}$, just because it has multiple even maybe infintie solutions shouldn't be so bad. one fear that I could see is $x^i = e^{-\pi/2}$ i to the power of i can equal that but could be $e^{2\pi n/2}$ where n is an int, as long as one possible answer is a solution then it is considered a solution.

Comment: See literature cited [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3411598/242).

Comment: Other than non-integer exponents, you have a field.